# .Net Data Access integration with Teradata 12.0

Tags: .net, odbc, managed, provider, teradata

I have am working on a .net application that integrates with a Teradata database version 12. Currently, we are using Odbc at the DAL to interface with the database.

Teradata have come out with the .Net Managed provider recently. I was wondering if there are any performance benchmarks available to compare ODBC with the .Net Managed provider. Does anyone know (from experience) if we are likely to see any significant performance gain by switching to the .Net Managed Provider for Teradata?

Any insights are highly appreciated!

Regards

AC

Answer (score 1):

You can find a comparison between the use of the .Net provider and the ODBC driver returning 40,000 rows from a data dictionary table here: [What's new in Teradata SQL Assistant 13.10 Edition 2](http://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/what-s-new-in-teradata-sql-assistant-13-10-edition-2)

From what the article shows there is a noticeable improvement in performance. Of course your mileage may vary. :)